# Prevent Language selection at ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, debian-installer, preseed

I would like to make a completely unattended installation of Ubuntu Server 14.04 from an USB drive where I extracted the `ubuntu-14.04.2-server.iso`

In `/syslinux/txt.cfg` of the USB drive, I added the following section

```
menu label ^Unattended Ubuntu Server installation
kernel /install/vmlinuz
append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true auto=true priority=critical url=http://website.com/preseed.cfg vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

But when I tried it, even before this menu shows up, I have to select a language (and therefore force me to have a manual intervention by pressing `enter`).

I found a [similar question](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/ubuntu-server-unattended-installation-custom-cd/) where it suggests to `echo en >syslinux/langlist` but I still get the language selection menu (with only one item).

How can I avoid this intervention ?

Comment: Use the search term 'preseed ubuntu install' to learn how to get a fully automated install. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preseed

Comment: Thank you, I did this already, but I didn't find the solution to my problem (yet).

Comment: @cremefraiche: I wrote the answer, could you up-vote it in order to increase it's visibility? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing what py4on suggested does simply shorten the list of available languages (to the extend of having one single element: `en`), but does not automate the language selection. It was probably working on older versions of Ubuntu but the requirement is for the Ubuntu Server 14.04. On 16.04 the instructions below may change to `isolinux` and `isolinux.cfg` instead of `syslinux` depending how you create the media.

In order to avoid this intervention at the language selection menu, the option `timeout` of `syslinux` should be set to a strictly positive value. After the specified timeout, the default language will be selected and the default booting entry of `syslinux` will be selected. The `timeout` parameter of `syslinux` represents a time in deci-seconds, and the default value is `0`, corresponding to an "infinite timeout".

Therefore, one could set `timeout 10` to make `syslinux` wait `1 second` before proceeding with the default value. The best place to put the parameter is in `syslinux/syslinux.cfg`. For example:

```
echo "timeout 10" >> syslinux/syslinux.cfg
```

In order to have a different language than `en`, I would suggest to proceed as py4on suggested by leaving only the chosen language in the `syslinux/langlist` file. For example:

```
echo "fr" > syslinux/langlist
```

References:

- http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX

Comment: It worked but after the timeout it also selected the default option from the install menu automatically.

Comment: @Katu this is the expected behavior of setting the timeout to a non-zero value. If you want your preseed to be the default option (for a zero touch imaging) you need to rewrite it as the first entry in the isolinux/isolinux.cfg when creating your ISO/USB.

Answer (score 4):

Before creating the ISO, follow the steps listed on the link below - I've done this myself. For preselecting language specifically do:

```
# cd /opt/ubuntuiso
# echo en >isolinux/lang
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/122506

Comment: Actually, I don't have a `isolinux` directory, neither a `lang` file. But I have a `syslinux` directory and a `langlist` file. I did put the `en` only on that file but I still have to press `enter` to select the only item in the list : `English`

Comment: Ok.. In case you haven't consulted it already, here's the relevant Ubuntu [setup guide for preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/i386/apb.html). See especially [this example preconfig file](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt). They do however state: "How to get the preconfiguration file included in the initrd is outside the scope of this document; please consult the developers' documentation for debian-installer." If this helps let me know and I'll update the answer for others.

Comment: Ok @Jav, this should fix it for you - when you've put that preconfig file together as you want it (based on the one I've linked to above) then follow the steps [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso) to edit the ISO. As above, please tell me if you're successful with this so I can update the answer and delete these comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't want to modify the `initrd.gz` because I need to put my custom `preseed.cfg` in the cloud (in order to change it after the CD creation). And anyway, the language selection that bothers me here occurs before the selection of the entry in `syslinu/txt.cfg` that loads the `initrd.gz` you suggest me to modify

Comment: Hi, it seems that your answer was not complete. I assembled the things to do in one answer. Could you up-vote it in order to increase it's visibility? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for a way to do the same, only just now found an answer to this.

I've only tried this with Ubuntu 16.04, but I suspect the answer will be the same for most Ubuntu versions - the `/isolinux` folder might be `/syslinux` for some versions I suspect.

The trick is to modify the `/isolinux/bootlogo` file, which is an uncompressed cpio archive.

What you need to do is extract the installer CD image to a directory I'll refer to as `${CDDIR}`. Then create a temporary folder in which we will store the `bootlogo` file contents, change to it and then:

Extract the original bootlogo file to the current folder:

```
cat ${CDDIR}/isolinux/bootlogo | cpio --extract --make-directories --no-absolute-filenames
```

Remove all non-English files:

```
ls *.hlp *.tr | grep -v "^en\." | xargs rm
```

Only keep "en" in the language list:

```
echo "en" > langlist
```

Auto-select "en" as the language choice:

```
echo "en" > lang
```

After this, I create the new bootlogo file with:

```
find . | cpio -o > /tmp/bootlogo.new
```

After this - you can copy your `/tmp/bootlogo.new` to the directory where your ISO was extracted, overwriting the original `bootlogo` file:

```
cp /tmp/bootlogo.new ${CDDIR}/isolinux/bootlogo
```

Now rebuild your image from the `${CDDIR}` contents, and you should not get a language choice anymore.

I was inspired by this post, which customizes the splash-screen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/412707/splash-screen-before-ubiquity-install

Comment: It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).